# Convert Cached CSS file to valid CSS

Tags: google-chrome, css, browser-cache

I have a cached file of css in my google chrome cache: visible in 'about:cache.' When I click on it, however, the file is a mix of binary and the css, not the original valid css file.

How can I strip all of the excess code to get my original css?

Comment: _Your_ original css, or _someone else's_ original css?  If it is your own file, where is your backup?  If not, there is a possibility that they've base64-encoded (or otherwise encoded) to make it harder for people to copy their styles.

Comment: My css. Deleted the original file but it exists in cache, otherwise I would have used the original file, obviously. No backup, obviously, or I would not have asked this question

Comment: Maybe drag the cached .css into Chrome and see if it will decompress/decrypt the non-text portions for you.  Of course with knowledge of the original .css, you'll have an easier time reconstructing it "from scratch".  And maybe it'll help remind you not to delete an original until you _absolutely don't need it anymore_.  I wish I could be more helpful, but this question is stuck too badly in bad ideas/bad assumptions.  Saving your fat from the fire, when you're the one playing with the fire isn't my specialty.